# Ensuring that a SELECT statement has a WHERE clause filtering on specific columns in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to force a SELECT statement on a table to include columns from that table in a WHERE clause, in Postgres?

For example, given a table `T` with columns `c1` and `c2` can I force a SELECT on table `T` to include a WHERE clause on column `c1`.

So that this statement would return some data:

```
SELECT * from T WHERE c1 = 'MyColumnValue'
```

But this statement would return no data or an error:

```
SELECT * from T
```

I understand that a user could simply include wildcards or the like to circumvent any strictures I might be trying to implement. This is an academic inquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is:

> can I **force** a SELECT on table T to include a WHERE clause on column c1.

Have a look at [row security policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-rowsecurity.html).

Though, a simpler option - I don't know if it suits your needs - would be to create a **view** which already restricts rows that can be returned from that table, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_t AS
SELECT * FRom T WHERE c1 = 'MyColumnValue'
```

You'd, of course, have to select from `v_t` view instead of the `t` table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data()
RETURNS SETOF your_table AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE c1 = 'MyColumnValue';
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks @mahmoud but I want to do this through a SELECT statement directly.